# Closure interpretation of a lattice

Tags: vector-spaces, order-theory, lattice-orders

Hello I am doing a bit of reading on lattices right now and I would appreciate some help. A species of algebra with meet and join operations and binary relation which is quasi ordering can be interpreted in different ways. One such interpretation is closure interpretation:

1. $\leq$ is relation of inclusion.
2. $a$ and $b$ are closed sets.
3. $\land$ is set intersection
4. Suppose there is a closure operation which assigns to every set $x$ and element $y$ which is its closure, such that $x \leq y$.
5. Set $a$ is closed when $y \leq a$, that is $y$ is a least closed set which contains $a$.
6. $\lor$ is operation which assigns to a pair of closed sets $a, b$ a least closed set which contains them both.

Now to my questions. If I choose to interpret $a$ and $b$ as vector spaces, then:

1. $a \leq b$ means $b$ is a subspace of $a$?
2. $a \land b$ means vectors common to both spaces i.e. if $U$ is a set of all vectors of a form $(x, y, 0)$ and $V$ of a form $(0, y, z)$ then $U \land V$ is all vectors $(0, y, 0)$?
3. $a \lor b$ means given $U$ of a form $(x, y)$ and $V$ of a form $(x, 0)$, then  $U \lor V$ is $R^2$?
4. Postulate of a semilattice $a \land b \leq a$ could be interpreted as set of vectors defined in 2. include $a$?

Does this make any sense? Thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: #5 makes no sense.

Comment: #3V.  A \/  B is the smallest subspace S with A,B <= S.

Comment: #5V misses the point, is confusing.

Comment: If #5 makes no sense what if we take K as a class of sets and x is an element of K then there is a closure operation which assigns to x its closure element y such that #4 holds, then #5 says x is a closed set when there is the least closed set y which contains x. Would this be still confusing ?